# How to install less on Oracle Linux Server

Tags: less, oracle-linux

Oracle Linux Server contains `more` utility, because it is smaller than `less` utility. How can one install `less` in this RPM based distro?

Answer (score 4):

If not already installed, this should do it :

```
yum install less
```

Edit: as you are actually running in a Docker environment, the correct way would be to rebuild it with less added.

Otherwise, you might try this:

```
docker exec -it <ol_container> yum install less
```

but the risk is high `yum` isn't installed either. If neither `yum` nor `rpm` are available, you might also simply copy the `less` binary (and dependencies if missing) from your host, e.g.:

```
docker cp /usr/bin/less ol_container:/usr/bin/less
```

Comment: install more to get less? :-)

Comment: @Lambert Thanks ! less is more, anyway ;-)

Comment: I tried yum, it asks for root. I am using docker image which is based on oracle/jdk:8 base docker image and can't figure out what the root password is. Anyway, it is different topic :)

Comment: I tried docker exec option, but it returns:

Loaded plugins: ulninfo
You need to be root to perform this command.

I'll tweak Dockerfile to install less - hopefully that'll do the job

Comment: The would be `sudo docker exec ...` but you still need to be root on the host.

Comment: I mean allowed to be root through sudo